# MemoryError with numpy arange

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, out-of-memory

I want to create an array of powers of 10 as a label for the y axis of a plot.
I am using the `plt.yticks()` with matplotlib imported as plt but this does not matter here anyway.
I have plots where as the y axis is varying from 1e3 to 1e15. Those are log plots.
Matplotlib is automatically displaying those with ticks with 1e2 steps and I want to have a step of 10 instead (in order to be able to use the minorticks properly).

I want to use the `plt.yticks(numpy.arange(1e3, 1e15, 10))` command as said but `numpy.arange(1e3, 1e15, 10)` result in a MemoryError. Isn't it supposed to output an array of length 13? Why does the memory gets full?

How to overpass this issue and not build the array manually?

I also tried using built-in `range` but it won't work with floats.

Thank you.

Comment: Er.. no, `1e3` is `1,000`, `1e15` is `1,000,000,000,000,000` you're asking for an array starting from `1,000` up to `1,000,000,000,000,000` in `10` increments

Comment: Oh i see my mistake. the step is an aditive factor and not mutliplicant.

Comment: What you need is `logspace`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the `logspace` from `NumPy` as

```
plt.yticks(numpy.logspace(3, 15, 13))
```

Here you give the starting and the last exponent (powers of 10) and the number of data-points in between. If you print the above mesh, you get the following

```
array([1.e+03, 1.e+04, 1.e+05, 1.e+06, 1.e+07, 1.e+08, 1.e+09, 1.e+10,
   1.e+11, 1.e+12, 1.e+13, 1.e+14, 1.e+15])
```

Comment: If you prefer to give your extrema as the number itself and not the exponent, you should consider using `np.geomspace()`.

Comment: @norok2: I think just writing (3,15) is simpler than writing (10e3, 10e15). But yeah, thanks for letting know this new option

Comment: It is simpler if you have extrema of that form `{base}e{exp}` with `base` a multiple of `10` (note that `10e3` would be identified by exponent `4` as the `{base}e{exp}` notation means `base * 10 ** exp`), but if you have extrema where `{base}` is not a multiple of `10`, then `np.geomspace()` is much cleaner than computing the exponent yourself.

Comment: Yeah, true that. In the present case, logspace looks more convenient for other bases, I agree

Answer (score 1):

You could also just do:

```
10. ** np.arange(3,16)
```

that decimal point is important, as without it you will overflow the default `int32` dtype for integers

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way to do this, rather than explicitly defining the tick positions, is to use a [`LogLocator`](https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.LogLocator) from the [`matplotlib.ticker`](https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html) module, and manually increase the number of ticks (by default, it will try to set a nice-looking number of ticks; i.e. so it doesn't look too cramped).

In this example, I set the number of ticks to 13 on the `Axes` on the right (using `numticks=13`), and you can see this increases the number of ticks so there is one on each integer power of 10.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

# Create figure and axes
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2)

# Make yscale logarithmic
ax1.set_yscale('log')
ax2.set_yscale('log')

# Set y limits
ax1.set_ylim(1e3, 1e15)
ax2.set_ylim(1e3, 1e15)

# On ax2, lets tell the locator how many ticks we want
ax2.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.LogLocator(numticks=13))

ax1.set_title('default ticks')
ax2.set_title('LogLocator with numticks=13')

plt.show()
```

[image]

EDIT:

To add minor ticks with this method, we can use another `LogLocator`, and this time set the `subs` option to say where we want minor ticks in each decade. Here I haven't set minor ticks on every 0.1 because it would be too cramped, so just done for a subset. Note that if you set minor ticks like this, you also need to turn off tick labels for the minor ticks, using a `NullFormatter`.

```
ax2.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.LogLocator(numticks=13))
ax2.yaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.LogLocator(subs=(0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8),numticks=13))
ax2.yaxis.set_minor_formatter(ticker.NullFormatter())
```

[image]

Comment: Oh thank you so much this looks very clear.
I believe `ax2.yaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.LogLocator(numticks=13))` would do the same for minorticks.

Why does the `minorticks_on()` command won't work automatically?

Answer (score 0):

In this case the function `logspace` from numpy is more suitable.
The answer to the example is
`np.logspace(3,15,num=15-3+1, endpoint=True)`